# NSData in NSCache swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, swift3, nscache

How can I save Data in `NSCache` in `Swift 3.0`?

```
lazy var cache = NSCache<NSString, AnyObject>()
```

When I try creating such array, I get the error:

> "Type 'Data' doesn't conform to 'AnyObject'"

In `Swift 2.0`, the following code worked:

```
lazy var cache = NSCache()
```

Comment: Have you tried `as NSData` ?

Comment: Thanks, that helped